# Android OpenGL ES point cloud rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a float array containing all points in a mesh, and I'm trying to render it as a point cloud, but no matter what, all I get is glitches [image: OpenGL glitches]

Here is the relevant code:

```
public Plane()
{
    ...

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertexCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
     ...
}

public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glPointSize(3);

    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCoords.length / 3);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

MyRenderer.java:

```
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i2) {
    // Sets the current view port to the new size.
    gl10.glViewport(0, 0, i, i2);
    // Select the projection matrix
    gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    // Reset the projection matrix
    gl10.glLoadIdentity();
    // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl10, 45.0f,
            (float) i / (float) i2,
            0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Select the modelview matrix
    gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    // Reset the modelview matrix
    gl10.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I got the rendering code from another StackOverflow question, but no matter what I do, all I get is what looks like static. For reference, I get the same (or a similar) effect when I try to triangulate it. (using and index buffer).

Comment: Are you enabling point-sprites? i.e. `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)`

Comment: I am not. Is that what is causing it? (Im on my phone, so i cant check now)

Comment: It's the only thing I could see that was evidently missing, might be the problem.

Comment: Alright. I'll enable it and check. Thanks :)